# Why there is no scanner.nextline() method between two nextInt() methods

Tags: java, methods, io, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter first number");
int FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Entered First Number is" + FirstNumber);
System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
int SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Entered Second Number is" + SecondNumber);
```

There is no error in the mentioned code everything is perfect but I have a doubt about why we didn't write a scanner.next line() method to handle enter key being pressed after the first number is entered on the console.

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt` reads the next token in the scanner.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

And further down

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by `Character.isWhitespace()`.

The documentation for [`Character.isWhitespace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) says that it returns true if the given codepoint

> [...]
> [...] is '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.
> [...]

Which means that `\n` is a separator, thus it's not part of any token, so you don't need to skip it with a dummy call to `nextLine()`

Answer (score -1):

`Scanner.nextInt()` does not read new lines, it only progresses in the current line. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: That is not correct, it does progress to a next line (because scanner by default tokenizes on whitespace). However, say it is consuming `1\n2\n`, after two `nextInt()` calls the remaining buffer is `\n`. If you then ask for `nextLine()`, you get an empty line (and the remaining buffer is then empty).